# Android uncatchable NullPointerException

Tags: android, crash, nullpointerexception, admob

I have a pretty annoying NPE in my app and can't find a solution. First the stack trace:

```
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at android.webkit.WebView.stopLoading(WebView.java:1737)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at c$a.run(Unknown Source)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
09-12 23:27:32.855: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The NPE occures when I switch the orientation very fast. Does somebody experience tha same? Is there a solution? Also I need to mention, that I use Admob. I don't know where else this NPE could occure in a WebView.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it always the same line of code that is throwing the exception? Can you post the code that is throwing the exception?

Comment: I don't know where this line is. My code definitively doesn't throw this exception, otherwise I could catch it. I've also noticed the same exception in an other activity, which also doesn't include a WebView. I'm pretty sure that Admob is the reason, because both of these activities have an AdView. But I don't know how I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question: With the right keywords I've finally found some good hits at Google. That is definitively an Admob issue. If your are interested in, take a look at this thread

http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/1f79640c499bbabc

Answer (score -1):

for orientation related crashes I usually find that adding

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

under the activity in which the crash occurs usually does the trick.