# Why would I receive a webkit.WebView error when I do not use WebView?

Tags: android

I received this error twice in the last three days on different devices. I do not use WebView at all in my app so I am a bit confused.

The only thing I can think of is AdMob but wouldn't that show up in the stack trace?

Here is the stack trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   android.webkit.WebView.stopLoading(WebView.java:1842)     at
>   c$a.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Update: In addition to the link Arhimed provided here is a link where an AdMob rep is discussing this as well
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/H3lkDEmburw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you said I am pretty sure this is an AdMob issue. The reason you don't see any "AdMob" occurrencies in the log is that AdMob comes as an obfuscated library jar. So `c$a.run(Unknown Source)` is a log enrty produced by an obfuscated code.

UPDATE:

This IS really related to AdMob. There is a related SO question: [Android uncatchable NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394375/android-uncatchable-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I somehow missed that when searching.